# data() doesn't read the data in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have the following simple code:

```
eventsMapJSON = d3.json("events.json", function(error, eventsMapData) {
    toplist = d3.select("#container")
        .append("ul");
    toplist.selectAll("li")
        .data(eventsMapData)
        .enter()
        .append("li")
        .text(function(d){
            return d;
        })
}
```

However, d3 doesn't read the data in the `selectAll` function, so the simple list I am trying to put in my container doesn't exist. On the debugger, I can see the `<ul>` tag, but not the `<li>` tags. Also, when I put breaking-point on the line `return d;`, the debugger doesn't stop there, which means d3 probably passes empty data.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox (I don't think that the browser is the problem, though)

Comment: The most likely problem is that your data variable is null because there was an error reading the file.  Have you tested `error` and `eventsMapData` to be sure that the first is null and the second contains your data?

Comment: The second most likely problem is that your JSON file isn't formatted as an array.  If it is formatted as one big hash-map/dictionary object, it will be interpretted as having a length of zero, and no elements will be created.  If that's the case, you can use [one of the d3 utility functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_keys) to turn the object into an array.

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem! Thanks a lot @AmeliaBR. Write your comments as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: To confirm: the problem was that your data was a hashmap, not an array?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.